# Apple devices browser no scrolling after using back-button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, scroll

I have some weird behaviour on the iPad 2 and iPhone 6 running iOS 9.3.1.

On my site there is a `<div>`, positioned `relative` with a fixed height, calculated by javascript on `window.load()` (jQuery).
In this `div` there's my scrollable content.

The site is running on Joomla 3.5 and I used a category to display some images as thumbnails for galleries.

On a normal site load there's no problem, clicking through works just fine an scrolling is working.

But **after entering a gallery and pushing the browsers back-button** (safari / chrome is behaving the same) the **content in not scrollable anymore**.
After changing the device orientation, selecting another site from the menu or reloading the scrolling works fine again.

On all other devices (Windows / Android) I have no problems at all.

JS code (shortened - it's all of my code that effects the specific `div`):

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    wheight = $(window).outerHeight();
    innerWrap.css(
      'max-height', 
      wheight - $('#wrapper').height() - $('footer').height() - 67 + "px"
    );
});
```

I already searched the web for iOS scrolling bugs but none of the fixes seemed to work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of your full code snippet for better understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

After finding that my javascript was not executed on `.load` when going back I searched specifically for this execution problem.

The problem was the internal cache of the system that is used to quickly display websites when going 'back' with the browser.

A little javascript snippet saved me:

```
jQuery(window).bind("pageshow", function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
       window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

After adding this the page does a true reload and renders normally, with working scrolling!